# How to write nested for loop so that the inner loop does not overwrite the first loop values

Tags: r

New poster on Stackoverflow but long time viewer. I could not find any previous posts that get at my specific question.

Basically, I am struggling with how to make use of a nested `for` loop for my problem. The issue is that the number of variables and outcomes will change with the use case, so I want a solution that is flexible for various permutations. I am not sure that `apply` would help me because I don't know in advance how many variables and outcomes will exist in any given use case.

The goal is to classify whether the outcome is correctly predicted by the variable (tp = true positive, etc).

The problem is that the inner loop causes the outer loop values to be overwritten, but what I want is for each `outcome` to be evaluated over each `variable` once independently. Not sure what the best way to do this is and any advice appreciated.

```
#Repex code

#Generate variable
variable <- c(1,2,3)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 0, nrow = 30))
for(i in 1:length(variable)){
  df[,c(paste0("variable",variable[i]))]<-as.vector(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=30))
}
df

#Generate outcome
outcome <- c(1,2,3)
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 0, nrow = 30))
for(i in 1:length(outcome)){
  df2[,c(paste0("outcome",outcome[i]))]<-as.vector(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=30))
}
df2

#Generate performance metrics of outcome and predictor
for (i in variable){
  for(j in 1:length(df2)){
    df[, c(paste0("tp.",variable[i]))] <- as.vector(ifelse(df[, c(paste0("variable",variable[i]))]==1 & df2[j]==1,1,0))
    df[, c(paste0("tn.",variable[i]))] <- as.vector(ifelse(df[, c(paste0("variable",variable[i]))]==0 & df2[j]==0,1,0))
    df[, c(paste0("fp.",variable[i]))] <- as.vector(ifelse(df[, c(paste0("variable",variable[i]))]==1 & df2[j]==0,1,0))
    df[, c(paste0("fn.",variable[i]))] <- as.vector(ifelse(df[, c(paste0("variable",variable[i]))]==0 & df2[j]==1,1,0))
  }
}
df

#bind the data for comparison and spot checking
df3 <- cbind(df2,df)

#here we see that only the final inner loop data are correct
df3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have 3 different `variable`s that you want to compare to 3 different `outcome`s, so you are making 9 comparisons. However, since you are labelling your columns only according to the `variable`, you only have three unique numeric suffixes (one for each value of `i`) pasted on to each statistic (tp, tn, fp and fn). You therefore only have 12 distinct column names.

At no point are you labelling the columns according to both the variable and the outcome. That means that every time your inner loop increments to the next outcome variable, you are over-writing the column in `df` that you wrote in the previous iteration of the loop.

In any case, how would you intend to keep track of which comparison you are making unless you use *both* the variable number **and** the outcome number to label your columns?

So you *could* do it this way:

```r
for (i in variable)
{
  V <- c(paste0("variable", i))
  for(j in seq_along(df2))
  {
    comp <- paste0(i, ".vs.", j)
    df[paste0("tp.", comp)] <- as.numeric(df[V] == 1 & df2[j] == 1)
    df[paste0("tn.", comp)] <- as.numeric(df[V] == 0 & df2[j] == 0)
    df[paste0("fp.", comp)] <- as.numeric(df[V] == 1 & df2[j] == 0)
    df[paste0("fn.", comp)] <- as.numeric(df[V] == 0 & df2[j] == 1)
  }
}

df3 <- cbind(df2, df)
```

Which will give you the structure you were looking for. It's a large data frame, so we'll just peek at it with `str`:

```
str(df3)
#> 'data.frame':    30 obs. of  42 variables:
#>  $ outcome1 : num  0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 ...
#>  $ outcome2 : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ outcome3 : num  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
#>  $ variable1: num  0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ variable2: num  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ variable3: num  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...
#>  $ tp.1.vs.1: num  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 ...
#>  $ tn.1.vs.1: num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ fp.1.vs.1: num  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 ...
#>  $ fn.1.vs.1: num  0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ tp.1.vs.2: num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ tn.1.vs.2: num  1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ fp.1.vs.2: num  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ fn.1.vs.2: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ tp.1.vs.3: num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
#>  $ tn.1.vs.3: num  0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ fp.1.vs.3: num  0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 ...
#>  $ fn.1.vs.3: num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ tp.2.vs.1: num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ tn.2.vs.1: num  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 ...
#>  $ fp.2.vs.1: num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ fn.2.vs.1: num  0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 ...
#>  $ tp.2.vs.2: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ tn.2.vs.2: num  0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ fp.2.vs.2: num  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ fn.2.vs.2: num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ tp.2.vs.3: num  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ tn.2.vs.3: num  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 ...
#>  $ fp.2.vs.3: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ fn.2.vs.3: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
#>  $ tp.3.vs.1: num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ tn.3.vs.1: num  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ fp.3.vs.1: num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
#>  $ fn.3.vs.1: num  0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 ...
#>  $ tp.3.vs.2: num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...
#>  $ tn.3.vs.2: num  0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ fp.3.vs.2: num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ fn.3.vs.2: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
#>  $ tp.3.vs.3: num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ tn.3.vs.3: num  0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 ...
#>  $ fp.3.vs.3: num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...
#>  $ fn.3.vs.3: num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
```

The other (and perhaps more sensible) way to do it is to have 3 data frames, one for each variable, and each with twelve columns (three sets of tp, tn, fp, fn). You can do this easily using `lapply`:

```r
df_list <- lapply(df, function(x)
{
  dfs <- list()
  for(j in seq_along(df2))
  {
    dfs[[j]] <- data.frame(ifelse(x == 1 & df2[j] == 1, 1, 0),
                           ifelse(x == 0 & df2[j] == 0, 1, 0),
                           ifelse(x == 1 & df2[j] == 0, 1, 0),
                           ifelse(x == 0 & df2[j] == 1, 1, 0))
  }
  setNames(do.call("cbind", dfs), 
           paste0(c("tp.", "tn.", "fp.", "fn."), rep(seq_along(df2), each = 4)))
})
```

Which gives you:

```r
df_list
#> $variable1
#>    tp.1 tn.1 fp.1 fn.1 tp.2 tn.2 fp.2 fn.2 tp.3 tn.3 fp.3 fn.3
#> 1     0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
#> 2     1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 3     0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 4     0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 5     1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#> 6     0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#> 7     0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 8     0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#> 9     1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#> 10    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#> 11    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
#> 12    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#> 13    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 14    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
#> 15    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
#> 16    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
#> 17    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#> 18    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#> 19    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#> 20    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 21    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 22    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 23    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
#> 24    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
#> 25    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#> 26    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#> 27    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#> 28    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 29    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 30    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#> 
#> $variable2
#>    tp.1 tn.1 fp.1 fn.1 tp.2 tn.2 fp.2 fn.2 tp.3 tn.3 fp.3 fn.3
#> 1     0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 2     1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 3     0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 4     0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 5     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
#> 6     0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 7     0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 8     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
#> 9     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
#> 10    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
#> 11    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
#> 12    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#> 13    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 14    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#> 15    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 16    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 17    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
#> 18    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#> 19    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#> 20    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 21    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 22    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
#> 23    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
#> 24    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 25    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#> 26    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#> 27    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#> 28    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 29    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 30    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#> 
#> $variable3
#>    tp.1 tn.1 fp.1 fn.1 tp.2 tn.2 fp.2 fn.2 tp.3 tn.3 fp.3 fn.3
#> 1     0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 2     0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
#> 3     0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 4     0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 5     1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#> 6     0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 7     0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 8     0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#> 9     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
#> 10    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
#> 11    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
#> 12    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
#> 13    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#> 14    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
#> 15    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
#> 16    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 17    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#> 18    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 19    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 20    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 21    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#> 22    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
#> 23    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 24    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
#> 25    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 26    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> 27    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#> 28    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
#> 29    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#> 30    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Many thanks. My next challenge is that the outcomes are only valid for the first observations 1-10 for outcome 1, observations 11-20 for outcome 2, and observations 21-30 for outcome 3. This method works great to apply over a range of variables, but in the end what I would like to do is parse the outcomes such that I am reporting the following:

Comment: @Jimbot thank you. If you found this answer helpful, please consider marking it as accepted to help others with similar problems find a solution.

Comment: Of course! I am just working on tidying up the results. Getting  very close using this method.

Comment: To close the loop, I pulled the results into an object for further manipulation based on my needs. 
sda <- lapply(df_list, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(x)))
sda.mat <- do.call(cbind, sda)
index6 <- seq_along(df2)*4*nrow(data) #index orig data
res <- c()
    for(i in seq_along(index6)){
      res[[i]] <- sda.mat[seq((index6[i]-min(index6)+1),index6[i]),]
      rownames(res[[i]]) <- paste0(c(rep("tp.",each=nrow(data)),rep("tn.",each=nrow(data)),rep("fp.",each=nrow(data)),rep("fn.",each=nrow(data))),rep(seq(1,nrow(data),by=1),times=4))
    }
sda.list <- do.call(rbind, res)